# libvte unicode font handling

Tags: x11, fonts, unicode, gtk

I am trying to display some ANSI text which contains characters from the [Unicode private use area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas). I have two fonts which contain these characters. The first is a PCF (bitmap) font, and the second is a TTF font, generated from the first and containing the exact same set of glyphs.

The PCF font is available in Debian and Ubuntu in the "tv-fonts" package and is called "teletext". The TTF versions are available [here](http://al.zerostem.io/~al/teletext/).

I display this text file by configuring my terminal to use one of my fonts, and then cat'ing [this file](http://al.zerostem.io/~al/teletext/termtest.txt).

This produces different results in different terminals:

Xterm can only use PCF fonts. With `xterm -fg white -bg black -fn teletext` I see the correct output:

[image: xterm pcf]

Terminator can use both PCF and TTF fonts. With PCF font the output is correct:

[image: terminator pcf]

But if I tell terminator to use a TTF font the output contains an unexpected character after the big "BBC" logo:

[image: terminator ttf]

The character in question is , unicode 0xee20. It is an empty space in both the PCF and TTF fonts.

When using xfce4-terminal the results are the same. Terminator and Xfce4-terminal both use libvte.

So my question:

- Why is libvte displaying the wrong glyph?
- Why does it behave differently between TTF and PCF? (Remember that both fonts contain an identical set of glyphs.)

Update: It seems that this isn't actually related to VTE but to Gtk, and possibly X11 itself. The same results can be seen when setting the font in a text editor, such as mousepad (which uses GtkSourceView.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `xterm` (and `xfd`) can use TrueType fonts, using the `-fa` option.  With the latter, you can see that `0xee20` is missing from the font:

[image]

Given that, xterm would show a missing glyph (because it uses only one font).  Likely vte is doing the same because none of the fallback fonts which it may be using has this particular *private use* code.

For comparison, here is a screenshot with `xfd` displaying the PCF font (which does have the glyph):

[image]

Whether the fonts are "identical" depends on how they were created (and maintained).  I see 7 missing glyphs on the screenshot of the TrueType font, and none on the PCF font.

Comment: I created the TTF font by converting the PCF, so I would have expected that they would contain an identical set of glyphs. Apparently they don't.